# How to integrate $\int e^{-\alpha x^2-\beta x^4}$

Tags: integration

How to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\alpha x^2-\beta x^4}dx$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and non-zero positive numbers? And $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-\alpha x^2-\beta x^4} x^k dx$ ?

And in the matrix form,why does the following integral hold?
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 \pi \det A)^{1/2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^T \cdot A^{-1}\cdot x}dx =1 $$
where $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ positive definite symmetric matrix.

How to get a general such integral for higher order tensors? If $A$ is  fourth order, how to get
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 \pi f(A))^{1/2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2} A_{ijkl} \cdot x_i x_j x_k x_l}dx =1 $$
for a function $f(A)$?

Comment: you should split this questions into different questions and also show some effort what you have tried so far

Comment: For the first question, it is doable. But, let us know what you already tried.

Comment: I know how to integrate $e^{-x^2}$ and $e^{-x^4}$ separately because they are gamma functions. but I have no idea how to integrate their multiple.